# ¿Como puedo eliminar palabras especificas de una cadena en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo este nombre  "Maria de la Cruz Navarrete de los santos" quisiera quitar las palabras "de la" y "de los" ¿Como puedo hacerlo para posteriormente guardar el resultado en un array?

Parte de mi código:

```
$user = "Maria de la Cruz Navarrete de los Santos"
$this->username = explode(" ", $user);
```

var_dump del array:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Maria"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "de"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "la"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "Cruz"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "Navarrete"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "de"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "los"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "Santos"
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías primero eliminar los elementos que no quieres y después hacer el explode

```
<?php
 $user = "Maria de la Cruz Navarrete de los Santos";
 //el metodo preg_replace sirve para remplazar caracteres dentro de un string por medio 
 //de una regex.
 $result = preg_replace('/de la|de los/m',"", $user);
 $this->username = explode(" ", $result);
?>
```